# OnSubmit With validate and CheckCheckBox

Tags: insertonsubmit

I'm wanting to use on submit to make sure a checkbox is checked, while also validating empty fields.
Here is the code I have:
OnSubmit="return checkCheckBox(Agree) & validate();">
I've looked at W3Schools, and on Google, yet can't find what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [jQuery's .submit()](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) function.